# How to print out a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I've been working on a way to enter numbers into a vector and then output it, but it always says the vector is out of range and pops up an extremely weird error. There isn't any compile errors, but when the program gets to the part of the code where I intended to print out the vector, it does this error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kH0D.png)

Can you not use a `cout` statement to print out vectors?

```
// Program to ask the user for numbers, and when they are done entering numbers, enter DONE. When DONE, print the vector

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#define DONE 20
using namespace std;

void l_userinput()
{
    int u_Answer;
    int vector_Size(0);
    int start_Size(0);
    vector<int> v_Name(start_Size);
    //intialize variables and the initial size of vector
    cout << "Please enter numbers and when you are done, type in DONE" << endl;
    while (!start_Size)
    {
        cin >> u_Answer;
        vector_Size++;
        if (u_Answer == 20)
            break;
        //Loop until you type in DONE
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vector_Size; i++)
    {
        cout << v_Name[i];
        //point of error, Vector out of range?
        if (i >= vector_Size)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    l_userinput();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* Please do not post screenshots of error messages. Include the text of the error in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems with your code. First, you are using additional variable to keep vector size. This is not needed - vector has `size()` member function for that.

Second, you are not populating your vector at all, instead, you just keep incrementing your counter - and thus you are trying to access elements which are not in the vector.

Third, your `#define` of `DONE` has nothing to do with user typing in word DONE. To finish the loop, user will have to enter 20.

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding `u_Answer` to `v_Name`, so when you try to print the contents out the vector is empty.  Trying to access any element of an empty vector results in Undefined Behavior.